# For loop Delay Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, infinite-loop

I need to Solve a delay differential equation with one free parameter, then plot the values of the solution. I am not able to write the code for this.

```
a=1000,10000,1000
For [i = 1 : 10]
 a (i) = a (i) + 100
  sold = First[NDSolve[{
   x'[t] == 43 - 0.0043*x[t] - 1.9*x[t]*v[t], x[t /; t <= 0] == 800,
   w'[t] == (1 - 0.5)*1.9* x [t]*v[t] - (0.17 + 0.2)*w[t], 
  w[t /; t <= 0] == 8,
   y'[t] == 0.5*1.9*x[t]*v[t] + 0.2*w[t] - 0.50*y[t], 
  y[t /; t <= 0] == 30,
  v'[t] == a*y[t] - 3*v[t] - 9.7*v[t]*z[t], v[t /; t <= 0] == 9,
  z'[t] == 4*v[t - 4.4]*z[t - 4.4] - 0.30*z[t], 
  z[t /; t <= 0] == 0.4}, {x, w, y, v, z}, {t, 0, 5000}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]
```

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the basic syntax of Mathematica first - The first three lines for example each contain syntax errors. Also, try to avoid `For` - it is generally not needed in Mathematica. Instead, you can use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) most of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ParametricNDSolve`,

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == 43 - 0.0043*x[t] - 1.9*x[t]*v[t], 
   x[t /; t <= 0] == 800, 
   w'[t] == (1 - 0.5)*1.9*x[t]*v[t] - (0.17 + 0.2)*w[t], 
   w[t /; t <= 0] == 8, 
   y'[t] == 0.5*1.9*x[t]*v[t] + 0.2*w[t] - 0.50*y[t], 
   y[t /; t <= 0] == 30, v'[t] == a*y[t] - 3*v[t] - 9.7*v[t]*z[t], 
   v[t /; t <= 0] == 9, z'[t] == 4*v[t - 4.4]*z[t - 4.4] - 0.30*z[t], 
   z[t /; t <= 0] == 0.4}, {x, w, y, v, z}, {t, 0, 50}, {a}];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[a][t] /. sol, {a, 0, 1, 0.5}]], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Taking `{t, 0, 5000}` is very time consuming, so I took `{t, 0, 50}`

Comment: What does the blue represent. I am not sure of it. Also what if i have two functions with free parameter a, and i need to plot them. Say if i also have f(x,a), then plot the x[t] versus f.

Comment: @YRaj http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html